# Is it really necessary to resurface cylinder and substitute piston?

Tags: motorcycle, piston, cylinder, rings

I believe this is common in motorcycle maintenance, I have heard in some places that, once you get the piston outside the cylinder there is no way back, you need to resurface the cylinder and get a new piston and seals, can I trust this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can absolutely reuse the piston if it isn't damaged.

There are [piston compressor tools](http://contentinfo.autozone.com/znetcs/product-info/en/US/grn/27039/image/3/) dedicated to slide the piston back into the cylinder.

Comment: And how about the cylinder, can I reuse it too without resurfacing?

Comment: @RodrigoAlencar that depends on what there are any prior scratches or scour marks present on the cylinder wall. If not, then the answer is no. You can find some epic engine rebuilds on YouTube where the builder doesn't see any need to have the cylinder walls sleeved